# Attempted to use an object that has ceased to exist. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80030102 (STG_E_REVERTED))

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Well I'm trying to programmatically add a new ListItem to an already existing List in my SharePoint 2010 website.

I've created a new webpart , added a single button to it with the following event handler

```
    protected void Unnamed1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SPSite currentSiteCollection = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.ID))
        {
            using (SPWeb currentWebsite = currentSiteCollection.OpenWeb(SPContext.Current.Web.ID))
            {
                SPListItem myNewItem = currentWebsite.Lists["myList"].AddItem();
                myNewItem["Title"] = "newItem1";
                myNewItem.Update();
            }
        }

    }
```

Added my webpart to the default page of the sharepoint 2010 site ... by unfortunately when I click the button I get this error

```
    Attempted to use an object that has ceased to exist. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80030102 (STG_E_REVERTED))
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Attempted to use an object that has ceased to exist. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80030102 (STG_E_REVERTED))

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[COMException (0x80030102): Attempted to use an object that has ceased to exist. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80030102 (STG_E_REVERTED))]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.SetDisableAfterEvents(Boolean bNewDisableAfterEvents) +0
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.SetDisableAfterEvents(Boolean bNewDisableAfterEvents) +124

[SPException: Attempted to use an object that has ceased to exist. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80030102 (STG_E_REVERTED))]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx) +27677298
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.SetDisableAfterEvents(Boolean bNewDisableAfterEvents) +207
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.AddOrUpdateItem(Boolean bAdd, Boolean bSystem, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bNoVersion, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Guid newGuidOnAdd, Int32& ulID, Object& objAttachmentNames, Object& objAttachmentContents, Boolean suppressAfterEvents, String filename) +26793884
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.UpdateInternal(Boolean bSystem, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Guid newGuidOnAdd, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, Boolean bNoVersion, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Boolean suppressAfterEvents, String filename) +26793214
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.Update() +161
   SLBWOA.Web.UCNewChecklist.UCNewChecklistUserControl.Unnamed1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +259
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +115
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +140
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +29
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2981
```

I've tried several solutions available on the forum and through google but with no luck.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "Sharepoint 2010" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem when my list definition contained, of all things, a `<Field Type="Choice">` with a `<Default>` element inside.

**Update:**
The problem occurs if I have a `<Field Type="Choice">` that doesn't allow an empty value, and I don't set this field to one of the valid values when creating the list item.

Comment: Same behavior when updating an item with a Yes/No field and not setting the value. Confusing since the type is bool? ie nullable, and the field is optional in SP. The field does have a default defined in the schema though.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error on every list view in one of sub-sites in SharePoint 2010, on default views also. It turned out that a user changed a time zone in site's regional settings to another time zone (+8), after I changed it back all started to work again )

Answer (score 0):

Did you try :

```
    protected void Unnamed1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SPSite currentSiteCollection = SPContext.Current.Site;
    using (SPWeb currentWebsite = currentSiteCollection.OpenWeb(SPContext.Current.Web.ID))
    {
        SPListItem myNewItem = currentWebsite.Lists["myList"].AddItem();
        myNewItem["Title"] = "newItem1";
        myNewItem.Update();
    }
}
```